# Browsers freezing, crashing, bugging

Tags: browser, crash, flash-player

I am running Windows 8.1 with the latest drivers installed and everything working just fine on my system, except for one thing: browsers. I tried many different browsers and all seem to have their own problems.

First I experienced that Google Chrome started to randomly freeze sometimes, and when I try to watch a YouTube video in full screen 3 things can happen: it works just fine, it will show the loading screen, won't load, and say something went wrong, or it will show black and green lines and crash the browser.

This happens on Opera too, note that that is running on Chromium core too. On Opera sometimes text disappears, and random cubes on the screen go black (only inside the Opera window).

On Firefox everything works fine, it won't crash, but when I try to watch a YouTube video two things can happen: it will work fine, or it will play the video with lag, which means it will play then for a moment a picture from the video 1 second ago appears and then it will pop back in to the right time, and this happens constantly.

I have no viruses on my computer (hopefully, as I have an antivirus and an antimalware) and I am not running any addons on any of the browsers. I haven't tried it on Internet Explorer, because well - no one uses that, that is very buggy on it's own. All other applications seem to go well, and if I try browsers on virtual machines or other OSes installed on my computer they will work just fine.

My computer is not old, and I have a fast processor, graphics card and 8 GB of ram. I think I might have some problem with Adobe Flash but even after reinstalling it it will still do the same, and on YouTube I am watching videos with the HTML5 player.

Comment: Please remove anything that is not relevant from this wall of text, and apply some basic formatting: an empty line to start new paragraphs. Thanks & success.

Comment: Try Internet Explorer. Many of these problems have something to do with it and we can't help if we don't know what IE does

Answer (score 1):

Since Youtube makes use of Flash Player, you might want to update it to the latest version. If the problem still persists, then it might be the graphics card. Update your graphics card drivers (I say this because you didn't specify if you've updated all the drivers). Just go to your graphics card manufacturer's website (you didn't specify your gfx Brand and model) to download the latest drivers. See if that would solve the problem.

Comment: I have two graphics card, with updated drivers, and it does this with both. On YouTube I am using the HTML5 viewer instead of the flash one, but it does it with flash too, and my flash is updated too. On Internet Explorer everything looks fine.

Comment: What are the model of the cards? Most cards are switchable. Meaning, they will only work on certain apps you have assigned or if an app demands high graphics processing power. You could try to assign Chrome to your switchable graphics card

Comment: I have a dedicated Intel graphics card and an NVidia card. I use the NVidia card on all applications, I set it to be the default.